# Dynamically changing height to match width with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a toggle that changes the width of the element and I want the height to match the width

I looked and found this and it works but it doesn't change after the toggle is clicked

So I'm looking for a solution that responds to the change

```
var cw = $('.child').width();
$('.child').css({'height':cw+'px'});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/47e84/1/

*Please note I'm fairly new to jquery*

Comment: You'll need to show how you're toggling.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here http://jsfiddle.net/47e84/

Comment: Just something to think about - http://jsfiddle.net/833Dj/ - just click on the red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the stored the value on page load and resetting the same value on each click, you should get the current width. Also there is no need to use `if` statements, for toggling the classes, `.toggleClass()` method can be used.

```
$('.feed-options-switch').on('click', function (event) {
    $('ul.feed-content').toggleClass('list grid');
    $('.work').css('height', function () {
        return getComputedStyle(this).width;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bqu2y/

Comment: That's the functionality I'm looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
$('.child').height(cw);
```

Comment: That gives me the same result as $('.child').css({'height':cw+'px'});

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you are trying to achieve. Is this better http://jsfiddle.net/wesleyskeen/47e84/2/

Comment: I was basically trying to them to be square based on the calculate width and height. @BlackSheep answer worked, thanks for the help anyway